# Splitting full page into div triangles and shapes and putting text into them

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I need to split the page in 3 or more "triangles" and center the info in them.

I have tried this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBZOoy

CSS:

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
.clipboard{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 20% 100%);clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 20% 100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #d3d0c9;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
.clipboard1 {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 50%, 20% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 50%, 20% 100%, 0 100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="clipboard">

</div>

<div class="clipboard1">
    <div class="text">
  <h1>testasdd</h1>
    </div>
```

I would like to have info in each "triangle". The text should be formatting according to the shapes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use clip-path with text inside the div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149144/how-to-use-clip-path-with-text-inside-the-div)

Comment: I think this link may help you [https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this consider a background layer then place the text where you want:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 49.5%,red 50%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,#ccc 50%);
}
.first {
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
.second,
.third{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:80vh;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  some text
</div>
<div class="second">
  some text
</div><div class="third">
  some text
</div>
```

You can also try like below:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.5%,blue 50%) right bottom/50.1% 50.1%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,blue 50%) left bottom/50.1% 50.1%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 49.5%,red 50%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,#ccc 50%);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.first,
.fourth{
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
.second,
.third{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:80vh;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  some text
</div>
<div class="second">
  some text
</div><div class="third">
  some text
</div>
<div class="fourth">
  some text
</div>
```

Comment: I think if content is more then this wont fit for it