# Fit html text in a (rotated) container as the container would be a "mask", but without clipping

Tags: html, css, mask

What I want to achieve looks like this (the automatic word-breaks aren't necessary):

[image: What I aim for]

Is this possible with pure htmland css? Or only if need be with svg or canvas object?

I tried to rotate a `div` and "unrotate" the `p`, like so:

```
<div id="container">
  <p class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero 
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
  </p>
</div>

#container {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

p.inner {
   transform: rotate(45deg); 
   text-align: center; 
}
```

…but that doesn't **"mask"** the text and if the text is too long it overflows.

I also tried to use a clipping path like the following:

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
```

But, that cuts out the "overflow" of the text.

Here is my more or less hopeless [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SunnyRed/gousLm75/):

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was able to adopt from this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149144/how-to-use-clip-path-with-text-inside-the-div) a solution is the following:

```
 #container {
background: #ddd;
height: 500px;
}

.shape {
  width: 50%; 
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff; 
}

.shape-left {
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 0%, 0 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0%, 0 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  float: left;
}

.shape-right {
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 100% 50%, 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 100% 50%, 0 0);
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 100% 50%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 100% 50%, 0 0);
  float: right;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}


<div id="container">
  <div class="shape shape-left">
  </div>
  <div class="shape shape-right">
  </div>
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <br />
<br />
...
  </p>
</div>
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/SunnyRed/1x09wn86/) defines two shapes, where nothing is "printed" (no background, nor text). The shapes float (one left, one right) and the text sits in between. This does indeed work, but to me, it still feels a bit hackish.

So if there is a better / cleaner solution, I would still very much appreciate it.